# How to solve "Error: tool" with RSAGA?

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, gis, saga

I am using R 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 14 64 bit version. I installed SAGA GIS 2.1.2 and RSAGA 0.93-6.

So far all seems to work fine.

rsaga.env() works, I use:

```
work_env <- rsaga.env(modules='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/')
```

because on the 64 bit the modules are located somewhere else.
Getting the libraries works as well:

```
> rsaga.get.libraries(path=work_env$modules)
 [1] "climate_tools"           "contrib_perego"          "db_odbc"                 "db_pgsql"               
 [5] "docs_html"               "docs_pdf"                "garden_3d_viewer"        "garden_fractals"        
 [9] "garden_games"            "garden_learn_to_program" "garden_webservices"      "grid_analysis"          
[13] "grid_calculus_bsl"       "grid_calculus"           "grid_filter"             "grid_gridding"          
[17] "grid_spline"             "grid_tools"              "grid_visualisation"      "imagery_classification" 
[21] "imagery_rga"             "imagery_segmentation"    "imagery_svm"             "imagery_tools"          
[25] "io_esri_e00"             "io_gdal"                 "io_gps"                  "io_grid_grib2"          
[29] "io_grid_image"           "io_grid"                 "io_shapes_dxf"           "io_shapes"              
[33] "io_table"                "io_virtual"              "pj_georeference"         "pj_proj4"               
[37] "pointcloud_tools"        "pointcloud_viewer"       "shapes_grid"             "shapes_lines"           
[41] "shapes_points"           "shapes_polygons"         "shapes_tools"            "shapes_transect"        
[45] "sim_cellular_automata"   "sim_ecosystems_hugget"   "sim_erosion"             "sim_hydrology"          
[49] "sim_ihacres"             "statistics_grid"         "statistics_kriging"      "statistics_points"      
[53] "statistics_regression"   "table_calculus"          "table_tools"             "ta_channels"            
[57] "ta_compound"             "ta_hydrology"            "ta_lighting"             "ta_morphometry"         
[61] "ta_preprocessor"         "ta_profiles"             "ta_slope_stability"      "tin_tools"              
[65] "tin_viewer"
```

But when I try to get the modules or anything else it gives a weird error:

```
> rsaga.get.modules("ta_preprocessor", env=work_env)
Error: tool
$ta_preprocessor
NULL
```

I found out that rsaga officially doesn't support higer versions of SAGA GIS 2.1.0 but when I try 2.1.0 I get the error described in another question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109497/rsaga-saga-cmd-2-1-0-error-inconsistency

How should I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of fixed it by compiling SAGA GIS 2.1.1 from source (http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20a%20Linux%20Unicode%20version/). When I execute a tool with RSAGA I do get another error; "Error: module", but the execution seems to do fine.

Also, SAGA GIS sometimes quits with a segmentation fault... but not to often.